# wget works with company proxy but apt-get and dpkg doesn't

Tags: proxy, apt

I am trying to install some software in a fresh install of Linux dnoseda 2.6.32-21-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 16 08:10:02 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux.
I already set the variables http_proxy, https_proxy and ftp_proxy and wget works perfectly.

But when I try with apt-get it blocks trying to conect directly to the site, without the proxy. Or the other behavior that I got is a lots of 407 authentication errors. But the wget of those packages works perfectly.

It's something missing? Can you help me?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the apt-parameters:

```
Acquire::http { Proxy "http://proxy:port"; };
```

inside a `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90proxy` file or similar.

**edit:** you need to do an `apt-get update` after changing the settings.

Comment: The file doesn't exists.Do I have to create 90proxy?

Comment: it works! but now dpkg doesn't work. It still trying to make a direct internet connection :(

Comment: dpkg shouldn't be connecting to the network. it should be using the packages that are downloaded. did you do an apt-get update after changing the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have those exported as root? or do you have them set as the user and using sudo apt-get?

If you are using sudo.. place the lines in

```
/etc/profile
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using sudo. I'm going to try to export the proxies variables in /etc/profile. Then I'm going to update the status.

Comment: It doesn't work, even after reboot. It seems to try to do a direct connection with the urls